# Unable to load service fabric application after upgrading to latest sdk(2.4.164)

Tags: azure, sdk, azure-service-fabric

I've upgraded service fabric sdk to 2.4.164. Now I can't load the service fabric application. Every time I open the solution, visual studio wants to upgrade the fabric project. Unfortunately it fails every time. It gives an error like:
“An error occurred during upgrade. The project will be restored to its original state. Invalid URI: The URI is empty.”

Log from VsProjectFault file:

```
Recoverable
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationProject.ProjectSystem.DiagnosticEventsPackageLoader.InitializeAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.UnconfiguredProjectImpl.AutoLoadMethodStateMachine.<<StartExecution>b__6_0>d.MoveNext()
```

What should I do to upgrade the project file successfully?

Comment: What version of "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio" do you have installed?

Comment: The installed version is 1.3.40930.2

Answer (score 0):

You likely only updated the SDK and Runtime from WebPI.   The version of tooling that matches 2.4 should be 1.4.xxxxx.   I believe the specific version should actually be 1.4.50124.2.   Can you install the "Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools - 2.4.164(VS2015)" from Web Platform Installer which should then upgrade successfully.

Comment: I've installed the latest version 2.5.216 now. 
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools - 2.5.216(VS2015)

I think once I manually uninstalled Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio from control panel. Now whenever I install SDK and tools through WEB PI installer, the tools for visual studio is not installed. Probably this is the problem. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you investigate the logs located here -> %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs\webpi and share what error code you getting back from the MSI installer?   Here is what I get when attempting what you describe

DownloadManager Information: 0 : MSI install return value for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio 2015 - Base Locale - 1.5.50311.1' is '0'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install return code for product 'Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio 2015 - Base Locale - 1.5.50311.1' is Success

Comment: I don't get any logs for Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio 2015. Here is the list of successful installations form Web PI installer:
[link](http://tinypic.com/r/5ob9mw/9)

Comment: So it isn't even trying to install it appears, maybe an issue with the WebPI feed.  What Operating System are you , SKU and version of Visual Studio 2015, and language?   FWIW, I uninstall from control panel all the time and then install via webpi (SDK and Tools) without issue, so don't think that is it. Have you tried on another machine or have the ability?   Out of curiosity, what if you uninstall all service fabric (sdk/runtime) from control panel and attempt to install Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and Tools - 2.4.164 (VS2015).  Does that version install?

Comment: Here is the direct link to the 1.5 tooling for Visual Studio 2015.   Can you attempt to install and see if this works. http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/E/2EE80964-74C2-4464-A7A1-4A587E8DE255/MicrosoftAzureServiceFabricTools.VS140.en-us.msi

Comment: It doesn't work event after uninstalling.
But it worked after installing it from the direct link. I'm still not sure why it's not working with WEB PI. It's really confusing. Btw thanks a lot for the direct link. At least I can work now.

Comment: Would love to know why I have to find a link in a comment on stack overflow to get this working yet none of the actual official service fabric pages provide a way to get to the proper version. Way to go Microsoft.